# step down from vs. step down as

Tags: meaning

I wonder how do the following differ from each other?

#1. Jeff Bezos will step down **as** chief executive later this year.

#2. Jeff Bezos will step down **from** chief executive later this year.

Answer (score 1):

The first is grammatical; the second is not. A suitable sentence using 'from' might be 'Jeff Bezos will step down from **the role of** or **the post of** chief executive later this year'